# How can you check a label's string and assign 0 to a non numerical string?

Tags: ios4

I do what's below but I 
am uncertain if it can be a problem, because it "works?"

```
myLabel.text = @"--";
float myString = [myLabel.text floatValue];


NSLog(@"What is myLabel '--' text as a float? %@",myLabel.text);
// output is:  '--'


NSLog(@"What is value of myString '--' as float? %2.2f",myString);
// output is:  0.00
```

I see nothing wrong with the outputs and formats. What i am having a question about is why does 
"float myString" convert '--'  to  0.00, this seems like it can be problematic.

If this is not an automatic action, what is the best way to assign a string to the value of 0.00, 
after it's been pulled from a label?

Comment: Because -- is not float value, that's why you get 0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `"--"` is not a valid float value, `floatValue` returns `0.0`.

From the `NSString` documentation:

> [...] returns 0.0 if the receiver doesn’t begin with a valid text representation of a floating-point number.

Comment: @hodji The documentation says that this is how the function works, so if it does what you need it to do, I see no reason not to use it.